# enabling JMX on java processes

Tags: jmx

I am aware of enabling JMX on java processes. The typical recommendation for a java process with out authentication or SSL access looks something like this:

```
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=5459
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false
```

I am able to understand the properties except the first one. What does
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote
signify?

My java process exposes JMX with just the following 3 java options as well and I am able to connect using jconsole.

```
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=5459
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false
```

What happens if I do not specify "-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote" parameter?

Answer (score 0):

From what I can tell, it looks like it's just historical, and no longer necessary in Java 6 and beyond.

> Under previous releases of the Java SE platform, to allow the JMX client access to a local Java VM, you had to set the following system property when you started the Java VM or Java application.
>
> com.sun.management.jmxremote
>
> Setting this property registered the Java VM platform's MBeans and published the Remote Method Invocation (RMI) connector via a private interface to allow JMX client applications to monitor a local Java platform, that is, a Java VM running on the same machine as the JMX client.
>
> In the Java SE 6 platform, it is no longer necessary to set this system property. Any application that is started on the Java SE 6 platform will support the Attach API, and so will automatically be made available for local monitoring and management when needed.

Ref: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/management/agent.html